# What is the longest length of word sequence that google can show as a autocomplete?

Tags: google-search

I am more curious to know what is the longest  length word-series that google shows as a auto suggest?.

Comment: If you mean the maximum length that it ***can*** show, it's down there in the answers, but if you mean the longest auto-completion from typing in a word or two, I found "`fédération internationale de football association fifa-strasse 20 8044 zurich switzerland`" from typing in "federation international."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from the source of the page: maxlength="2048"

Comment: which is like 2 Megabytes so its good on them :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try searching for one.

Comment: yeah but that will be specific to my search i wanted if someone knows the pefect number